# Adding default handle_info in __using__ macro

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

I'm trying to make a little wrapper around [ExIrc](https://github.com/bitwalker/exirc), but I have encountered a bit of a problem. `__using__` macro appends ast to the beginning of the module and I want to append a function definition to the it's very end as default `handle_info`. I could possibly do it manually in every single module that uses that wrapper, but I'm more than sure that I will forget that at some point of time.

My current implementation of wrapper:

```
defmodule Cgas.IrcServer do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      use GenServer
      alias ExIrc.Client
      require Logger
      defmodule State do
        defstruct host: "irc.chat.twitch.tv",
          port: 6667,
          pass: unquote(Keyword.get(opts, :password, "password")),
          nick: unquote(Keyword.get(opts, :nick, "uname")),
          client: nil,
          handlers: [],
          channel: "#cohhcarnage"
      end
      def start_link(client, state \\ %State{}) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [%{state | client: client}])
      end
      def init([state]) do
        ExIrc.Client.add_handler state.client, self
        ExIrc.Client.connect! state.client, state.host, state.port
        {:ok, state}
      end
      def handle_info({:connected, server, port}, state) do
        Logger.debug(state.nick <> " " <> state.pass)
        Client.logon(state.client, state.pass, state.nick, state.nick, state.nick)
        {:noreply, state}
      end
      def handle_info(:logged_in, config) do
        Client.join(config.client, config.channel)
        {:noreply, config}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And a sample module that uses it:

```
defmodule Cgas.GiveAwayMonitor do
  use Cgas.IrcServer,
    nick: "twitchsniperbot",
    password: "token"
  require Logger
  def handle_info({_type, msg, %ExIrc.SenderInfo{user: "cohhilitionbot"} , _channel}, state) do
    if String.downcase(msg) |> String.contains?("giveaway") do
      IO.inspect msg
    end
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

In it's current state it craches sooner or later because of IRC random messages that I don't care about.

And I need to append something like to the end of the file to handle all the random cases:

```
def handle_info(_msg, state) do
  {:noreply, state}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have combined a your answers with 3rd chapter of `Metaprogramming Elixir` by Chris McCord and I ended up with this:

```
defmodule Cgas.IrcServer do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :handlers, accumulate: true
      @before_compile Cgas.IrcServer
      #Some code gen
    end
  end
  defmacro expect_message(pattern, do: action) do
    quote bind_quoted: [
      pattern: Macro.escape(pattern, unquote: true),
      action: Macro.escape(action, unquote: true)
    ] do
      @handlers { pattern, action }
    end
  end
  defmacro __before_compile__(_env) do
    quote do
      use GenServer
      #Some important necessary cases
      compile_handlers
      def handle_info(message, state) do
        IO.inspect({:id_does_not_work, message})
        {:noreply, state}
      end
    end
  end
  defmacro compile_handlers do
    Enum.map(Module.get_attribute(__CALLER__.module, :handlers), fn ({head , body}) ->
      quote do
        def handle_info(unquote(head), state) do
          unquote(body)
          {:noreply, state}
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

And a example client module

```
defmodule Cgas.GiveAwayMonitor do
  use Cgas.IrcServer,
    nick: "twitchsniperbot",
    password: "token"

  expect_message { _type, msg  , %ExIrc.SenderInfo{user: "cohhilitionbot"} , _channell}  do
    if String.downcase("ms") |> String.contains?("giveaway") do
      IO.inspect "ms"
    end
  end

end
```

I think it's nice because now every single handle_info clause is grouped together, it has default catch clause and it's kinda pretty and state which i don't care about but it's needed for underlying client is automagically passed.

Comment: That is nice :) You don't have to remember to put handle_info at the end of file, you don't have to remember all `handle_info` clause combinations that are available. This is explicit and when reading modules I can clearly see where to search for bugs. I am not sure why do you need to use `before_compile`. Can't you just put everything in the `using` macro with this approach?

Comment: No, because in the __using__ the @handlers is always nil, because compiler haven't reached any expect message yet. At least that what i read in Criss's book. And before_compile is executed after compiler went through whole file.

Comment: That makes sense. So you probably can't get any simpler than that. Nice :)

Answer (score 5):

You can inject the catch-all `handle_info` in a `@before_compile` hook:

> #### `@before_compile`
>
> A hook that will be invoked before the module is compiled.
>
> Accepts a module or a tuple `{<module>, <function/macro atom>}`. The
>   function/macro must take one argument: the module environment. If it’s
>   a macro, its returned value will be injected at the end of the module
>   definition before the compilation starts.
>
> When just a module is provided, the function/macro is assumed to be
>   `__before_compile__/1`.
>
> Note: unlike `@after_compile`, the callback function/macro must be
>   placed in a separate module (because when the callback is invoked, the
>   current module does not yet exist).
>
> Example
>
> ```
> defmodule A do
>   defmacro __before_compile__(_env) do
>     quote do
>       def hello, do: "world"
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> defmodule B do
>   @before_compile A
> end
> ```

[Source](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#module-compile-callbacks)

Example:

```
defmodule MyGenServer do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use GenServer
      @before_compile MyGenServer

      def start_link do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    quote do
      def handle_info(message, state) do
        IO.inspect {:unknown_message, message}
        {:noreply, state}
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyServer do
  use MyGenServer

  def handle_info(:hi, state) do
    IO.inspect {:got, :hi}
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end

{:ok, pid} = MyServer.start_link
send(pid, :hi)
send(pid, :hello)
:timer.sleep(100)
```

Output:

```
{:got, :hi}
{:unknown_message, :hello}
```

Comment: Why does it help?

Comment: `@before_compile` injects the code after all the actual code that's written in the module by the user.

Comment: Ok. I'll test it right away.

Edit: Works like a charm

Comment: @Haito While this answer will work I proposed another approach to solving this problem that may result in code that is easier to debug.

Comment: @Haito Also, putting any other function in the module (like private helper) may break the code in the solution above.

Comment: @tkowal what do you think about my new approach?

Answer (score 1):

The below would be another approach to this problem: one might go further and define additional `handle_info` matches directly inside `use`:

```
defmodule M do

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [his: opts |> Keyword.get(:handle_infos, [])] do
      def handle_info(list) when is_list(list) do
        IO.puts "[OPENING] clause matched"
      end

      for {param, fun} <- his do
        def handle_info(unquote(param)), do: (unquote(fun)).(unquote(param))
      end

      def handle_info(_) do
        IO.puts "[CLOSING] clause matched"
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule U do
  use M, 
      handle_infos: [
        {"Hello", quote do fn(params) ->
                    IO.puts("[INJECTED] with param #{inspect(params)}")
                  end end}
      ]
end

U.handle_info("Hello")
#⇒ [INJECTED] clause matched with param "Hello"
U.handle_info(["Hello"])
#⇒ [OPENING] clause matched
U.handle_info("Hello1")
#⇒ [CLOSING] clause matched
U.handle_info("Hello")
#⇒ [INJECTED] clause matched with param "Hello"
```

This way one have more explicit control on what is related to `handle_info` function.

Comment: Hmm.. Nice but i think it's kinda syntactically ugly, but I think we might be getting there.

Comment: Well, the intent was to show the technique, one definitely might wrap call to quote into a handy macro, declare functions in more readable way etc. I just wanted to show the, say, pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but what you are trying to achieve is something I would classify as a code smell.

Elixir takes pride in being very explicit. When debugging a piece of code I can look at source and see the flow. If there is a function not defined in this module I can check beginning of the file for `use` to find where this function is defined. In your example while debugging a message that does not fit other types I would be very confused that the code doesn't throw `FunctionClause`.

Instead I propose to add this inside `Cgas.IrcServer`:

```
  def handle_info({:connected, server, port}, state) do
    ...
  end
  def handle_info(:logged_in, config) do
    ...
  end
  def handle_info({_type, msg, %ExIrc.SenderInfo{user: "cohhilitionbot"} , _channel} = msg, state) do
    do_handle_info(msg, state)
  end
  def handle_info(_msg, state) do
    {:noreply, state}
  end
```

And in your module `Cgas.GiveAwayMonitor` instead of defining `handle_info` define `do_handle_info`:

```
def do_handle_info({_type, msg, %ExIrc.SenderInfo{user: "cohhilitionbot"} , _channel}, state) do
  if String.downcase(msg) |> String.contains?("giveaway") do
    IO.inspect msg
  end
  {:noreply, state}
end
```

One drawback of this solution is that you need to know at least function head up front. If you don't know that, you could do something like this in the last `handle_info`:

```
def handle_info(msg, state) do
  try do
    do_handle_info(msg, state)
  rescue
    e in FunctionClauseError -> {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

I feel it is a little less hacky then injecting function clauses into module and it achieves the same result: you don't have to repeat yourself.

Comment: I think this might not work so good, because i would have to constantly changing do_handle_info sig when I'll be adding new functionalities. Now I need only the msg and state, but some day I might need to access other things from that tupple. But I like this approach.